# Time complexity and Master's theorem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to get a better understanding of Master's Theorem and time complexity. I found some examples online that I am practicing. Is my work correct?

```
T(N) = 3T(N/3) + O(N)
```

Will have time complexity Θ(n), because log(base 3) 3 = 1. Thus, Θ(n^1) + O(N) is simplified to Θ(n).

```
T(N) = 3T(2N/3) + O(1)
```

This one I don't understand. I Know it is the stooge sort algorithm, but if using master's theorem, wouldn't a and b both be 3, making log(base 3) 3 = 1, making this Θ(n)? I know that is incorrect but I am having a tough time understanding master's theorem.

```
T(N) = 4T(N/2) + O(N)
```

Will have time complexity Θ(n^2), because log(base 2) 4 = 2. Then, N^(log(base 2) 4) = N^2

```
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(N log(N))
```

Here I am thinking it is simply O(N log(N)), since log(base 2) of 2 is one.

Comment: The first case is O(n log n); read the theorem carefully. in the second, b = 3/2.

Comment: Do you mean the first of four examples? Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: For T(n) = 3T(n/3) + O(n) (I assume you mean Θ(n) for that last summand), you get T(n) = Θ(n log n) because 1 = log_3 3, and so the second case (according to wiki) of the theorem applies. I don't think the theorem applies to T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n log n).

Comment: I do mean big O not, big theta. How much of a difference does that make?

Comment: The difference is that for f = o(n), you get T(n) = Θ(n) while for f = Θ(n), you get T(n) = Θ(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

**by master theorem :-**

```
if 
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n^k)

if loga/logb > k  then T(n) = O(n^(loga/logb))

if loga/logb < k  then T(n) = O(n^k)

else T(n) = O(n*logn)

 1. a = 3 b = 3 k=0  loga/logb = 1 = k    hence T(n) = O(nlogn)
 2. a = 3 b = 3/2 k=0 log3/log(3/2) > 1 > k  hence T(n) = O(n^(log3/log(3/2)))
 3. a = 4 b = 2 k = 1 log4/log2 = 2 > 1  hence T(n) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: Okay.. your explanation helps a lot more than those that I have seen. But how would the fourth one work since f(x) is not in the form (n^k), but rather, f(x) = N log N?

Comment: @VikramBhat That is wrong; while n log n is in small-omega of n, the master theorem doesn't apply here. The correct answer is n log^2 n for the fourth one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first elaborate on the master theorem and analyze your four cases.

[image]

In the above picture, it shows that at each level the complexity is:

[image]

And we sum up all computations from all levels and get the total:

[image]

Then we only need to analyze the total function which is a geometric series and determined by the multiplicative factor(or common ratio): `a/b^d`.

1. If the common ratio is bigger than one, there will be exponential growth towards the last term:
   [image]
   which is the big O when `a/b^d > 1` or `d<log_b a`.
2. If the common ratio is less than 1, there will be an exponential decay starting from the first term `n^d` which is the dominant one or the big O when `a/b^d < 1` or `d > log_b a`.
3. If the common ratio is equal to 1, the series will be a constant sequence and we sum up all terms:
   [image]

---

In **your case 1** where `T(N) = 3T(N/3) + O(N)`, we first see the common ratio `a/b^d = 3/3^1=1`.

And for **your case 2** `T(N) = 3T(2N/3) + O(1)` it would be `a/b^d = 3/(3/2)^0 = 3 > 1`(where a = 3, b = 3/2 and d = 0) and hence the big O would be: [image].

For **your case 3** `T(N) = 4T(N/2) + O(N)` a would be 4, b would be 2 and d would be 1.

For **your fourth case** `T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(N log(N))` the common ratio would be smaller than 1 since `a/b^d = 2/2^1.x` where `d > 1`, then the geometric series would be exponentially decaying. And hence the first term `n log n`  would dominate the series and hence it would be the big O.

References:

1. https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithmic-toolbox